# Pull TextBox Values from .RDL file using PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, reporting-services, rdl

I am currently grabbing a set of RDL files from a ReportServer database, and loop through each .RDL (which is an XML file) and write the value of each text box int the RDL to file (or just to the screen at this point).

I can get the files out of the Database no problem, and I am able to loop through each file, but I cannot consistently get all of the textbox values in each table.  Sometime tables are skipped.  My initial try worked on a very basic RDL file. The below example was getting the names of the text boxes in the header row.

```
$FilePath = "C:\XML\Report.rdl"
[System.Xml.XmlDocument]$RDLFile = New-Object system.Xml.XmlDocument
$RDLFile.load($FilePath)
clear

      foreach($textbox in $RDLFile.Report.Body.ReportItems.Table.Header.TableRows.TableRow.TableCells.TableCell)
            {
                  $textboxname = $textbox.ReportItems.Textbox.Name
                  Write-Host($textboxname)
            }
```

The RDL this worked on was a simple  RDL with a single 3 column data grid on it.  When I try the same method on more complex reports, it bombs, or grabs only some of the fields.

Comment: Couldn't you just do something like `[XML]$RDLFile = GC "C:\XML\Report.rdl"`?

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't do anything to solve the problem.

Comment: Right, sorry, was just a comment on the script in general, it wasn't an answer at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using SelectNodes method with XPath selector. 
Note: You need to define the namespace before you can use XPath selector. Also use 'ns:' in the XPath selector.

Here is an example:

```
$rdl = New-Object XML
$rdl.Load($reportFullPath)
$nsm = New-Object Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($rdl.NameTable)
$nsm.AddNamespace("ns", $rdl.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI)
$elements = $rdl.SelectNodes("//ns:Textbox", $nsm)
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that might work is trying the selectnode method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes.aspx

It'll let you pick an xpath which might be easier than dot notation

```
$FilePath = "C:\XML\Report.rdl"
[System.Xml.XmlDocument]$RDLFile = New-Object system.Xml.XmlDocument
$RDLFile.load($FilePath)
$TableNames = $RDLFile.SelectNodes("//ReportItems/Textbox/Name")

foreach($textbox in $TableName){
    $textbox
    ##Or $textbox.attribute if trying to pull an attribute
}
```

I tried the above with powershell 3 (with a similar xml), I don't know if it'll work the same with powershell 2 though.